# Is there any way to get the full border when adding a border to a fieldset element?

Tags: html, css, legend, fieldset

When I add a border to `fieldset` element and then drag the `legend` down to work as a heading of sorts, the gap in the `fieldset` remains.

Is there a way to have the entire border, without adding a wrapper `div` and setting the border on that?

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### CSS

```
fieldset legend {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -40px; 
    background: transparent; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/p67re/).

Comment: What browser are you testing with?

Comment: For instance, in Firefox, it doesn't look like your screenshot.

Comment: @thirtydot I'm a recent Chrome convert (though Firefox 4 may steal me back) so that is why I may only be noticing this behaviour now.

Comment: I *think* I've found a way. I'm testing it and trying to make it less icky before I post an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested in IE7/IE8 and recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

It looks the same in all of them, with the exception that IE7 is adding a little space on the left.

I had to add an innocent little wrapper `span`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ErZEj/

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><span>I am</span></legend>

        <div style="margin-top:80px">dsfsdf</div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
fieldset {
    border: 2px dotted #333;   
    height: 340px;
    position: relative
}
fieldset legend {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
legend span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -60px;
    white-space: nowrap /* or define width */
}
```

Comment: Yay! Btw: I just noticed that `top: 40px` seems to work just as well (and is clearer to read).

Answer (score 2):

Look at this jquery fiddle : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/gtNnT/)

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this too, but it won't support < IE8, which means it is not suitable for my required browser compatibility (but +1  because it is the best solution I've found so far).

Comment: Simple solution : Update to a new version of IE i.e IE8 =)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `position: relative` on the `fieldset` and absolutely position the legend:

```
fieldset {
    border: 2px dotted #333;   
    height: 340px;
    position: relative;
}

fieldset legend {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent; 
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YHhPP/

This renders the same way in Gecko and WebKit for me, the original fiddle has the gap in WebKit but the legend is ignoring the `bottom:-40px` in Gecko.

You can also try floating the legend: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Gwv4M/1/

```
fieldset {
    border: 2px dotted #333;   
    height: 340px;
}

fieldset legend {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

But IE7 and IE8 seem to butcher that one too.

Comment: Hey, you may be onto something +1. Do you know if this will work in IE7?

Comment: @alex: It doesn't. See http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ + http://fiddle.jshell.net/ambiguous/YHhPP/show/light/ Also doesn't work in even IE8 T_T

Comment: Odds are that you're going to have a special "beat IE7 into submission" stylesheet anyway so piling more hacks into it for this might not hurt too much. IE8 doesn't seem to like it either.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just leave the legend tag out and use something else for the header inside the filedset.

Comment: Because I believe the `legend` is the most semantically correct element to use (I care about people with disabilities that rely on screen readers, for example).

Comment: If you do this can you not set "display: none" for the legend so the screen reader uses it for the prompt but it is not displayed as part of your visuals and then place your visual header with some form of formatted text.

Comment: Can you confirm it won't read it, in addition, will it then repeat the title twice?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the Fieldset tag, but I know that you can have labels on a form to help prompt screen readers that are marked hidden or display: none and the prompts are still read.  I would think that the fieldset tag would work similarly.